# Mongo DB Entity Binding in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have the below document format in MongoDB

Document 1:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0d30ae942267c0c8f6229d"),
    "Expression" : "[tag] = 'Druck1' && [status]='OK'",
    "Name" : "Druck1 is running",
    "Actions" : [ 
        {
            "TemplateName" : "Warning",
            "Tags" : "[tag]",
            "Roles" : [ 
                "Group_AdUser", 
                "Group_FieldServiceCoordinator", 
                "Group_FieldServiceTechnician", 
                "Group_Roaster", 
                "Group_ServiceAdmin", 
                "Group_ServiceManager", 
                "Group_ServiceSales", 
                "Group_TSCUser", 
                "Group_WorkshopRepairCoordinator"
            ],
            "IsActive" : true,
            "SequenceNo" : 0,
            "Type" : "EventMessageAction"
        }
    ],
    "IsActive" : true,
    "TargetUsers" : null,
    "TargetGroups" : null,
    "Type" : "Rule"
}
```

Document 2:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0bc01fcd8d2966e0fdf2f2"),
    "Expression" : "HasProperty('category') && [category] = 'Temperature'",
    "Name" : "RTF Machine Temperature (History Data)",
    "Actions" : [ 
        {
            "Table" : "[machinename]",
            "Key" : "'RTF'",
            "Value" : "[value]",
            "Timestamp" : "[timestamp]",
            "ExpirationDate" : "[timestamp]",
            "Icon" : "''",
            "Color" : "''",
            "Text" : "''",
            "Category" : "[category]",
            "IsActive" : true,
            "Type" : "HistoryDataAction",
            "SequenceNo" : 0
        }
    ],
    "IsActive" : true,
    "TargetUsers" : null,
    "TargetGroups" : null,
    "Type" : "Rule"
}
```

Is there any way, I can fetch the above record w.r.t my entities as below:

Rule Entity:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Rule
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Expression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public IEnumerable<Action> Actions { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

Action Entity:

```
public class Action
    {
    }
```

History Action Entity:

```
 [DataContract]

public class HistoryDataAction : Action
    {
        public HistoryDataAction()
        {
        }


        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("table")]
        public string TableExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("key")]
        public string KeyExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public string ValueExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public string TimestampExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("expiration_date")]
        public string ExpirationDateExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("icon")]
        public string IconExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("color")]
        public string ColorExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string TextExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("category")]
        public string CategoryExpression { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("is_active")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public virtual string Type
        {
            get { return this.GetType().Name; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("sequence_no")]
        public int SequenceNo { get; set; }
    }
```

Event Action Data:

```
[DataContract]
    public class EventMessageAction : Action
    {
        public EventMessageAction()
        {
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Tags { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int SequenceNo { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there something like TypeNameHandling which we achieve by $type available for MongoDB. I need to fetch the document list and map it accordingly to my entity. If the action type is HistoryDataAction then it should go for HistoryDataAction entity else for EventMessageAction entity.

The normal collection.Find() doesn't work here. It successfully gives me the Rule entity but fails to bind the Action entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate your base type (Action) with the BsonKnownTypes attribute. E.g:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(EventMessageAction),
    typeof(HistoryDataAction))]
public class Action
{
}
```

[Update]
Your data doesn't contain the type key required by the driver to know what type to map the data to. If possible, rename or duplicate your "Type" key to "_t"

Comment: This didn't work. I get action count as 1, but the class isn't getting mapped.

Comment: It worked now. Actions are coming according to the type.